# SQL Server Agent - Print PDF

Tags: sql-server, jobs

So I need to download, save, and print a pdf on demand. My current SSIS flow is as follows:

1. Read and assign variables from table
2. Create URL and download .pdf report from SSRS Server
3. Print PDF from specified folder to specified printer using powershell arguments:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "<<.ps1 file path>>'<<variable1>>' '<<variable2>>'"
```

4. .ps1 script:

```
Start-Process $file -Verb PrintTo $printer_Name
sleep 10
taskkill /im acro* /f
```

The job is running under proxy with admin rights. The job reports completed successfully. The logs show the last line of the .ps1 file is being reached.

This all works when executed manually both in visual studio and when the package is executed manually from the server. But when the job executes the same statement, nothing happens.

I have tried this both as a powershell command job, and now a cmd command.

Why isn't anything working?

SQL Server 2014

Comment: Does the ID running the job have permissions to save the file to the location you listed?

Comment: *"SQL Server 2014 R2"*? There was no R2 of SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Powershell on SQL Server agent is weird. Add $ErrorActionPreference = "stop" to the start of your Powershell script and that should cause the step to fail if the Powershell command fails and give you the error. As Brad says, it is likely the account the step is running as does not have sufficient permissions in the OS context

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Initially, I was guessing could it be permission issue to the printer.
Later, I tried to run with Window Task Scheduler instead and it printed perfectly.
Would still be nice to know why it did not work with agent job.
Interestingly, I tried to run agent job with different print exe
adobereader, ghostscript and PDfToPrinter. All 3 shows success in job, but did not reach printer queue.
I tried to have 7zip instead of using the printer execution file, and the 7zip was successfully executed via agent job.
I wonder if agent job has issue in general for using printer execusion.

Comment: I removed the part which does not fit [answer] at all. But you can still get closer to it by [edit]ing. If you do not intend this to be an actual answer please delete it. Taking the [tour] is recommended.